# Image preloading interferes with Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I preload a large number of images on a page. However, this approach queues all Ajax requests at the end, making the interface unresponsive until all images are loaded. What would be your favorite approach to bump the priority on the Ajax requests?

Comment: maybe loading couple images at a time, and when they're loaded - load next couple of images

Comment: https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply. Probably worth a look.

Comment: Grouping many images into a single request will only take away the ability to call Ajax in between the image loads.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a subdomain for either the image requests or the AJAX requests. That way, you can sidestep the browser limit on same domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

No ajax call should make the interface unresponsive. Google Instant sends ajax requests one after the other, without your Firefox/Chrome becoming unresponsive. Ajax nature is asynchronous. Can you provide more details please? 
Also I recommend [predictive fetch pattern.](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Predictive_Fetch)

Comment: If there are more than 2-6 (dependent on browser) requests queued for the same domain, then it's quite possible for Ajax requests to hang until other requests have completed.

Comment: What I meant by unresponsive is that my ajax calls do nothing for quite some time (not responding).

Comment: You said "preload". Why don't you just insert those images in the HTML markup and let the browser get them ordinarily, not via ajax call?

Comment: No, not display:none. If you want to not show those images, till they're fully loaded, then you should have full control over it's load process, which means that you have to use ajax (to use readyState = 4 where the content is fully loaded). But if it doesn't matter, then you can let the images be rendered slowly in browser.

Comment: I need to preload images that will displayed on the page only as a result of user interaction. Think Slideshare. How would checking for the image's completion help me squeeze unpredictable Ajax requests in between images?